# File upload script apparently not executing until upload has completed

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, multipartform-data, fine-uploader

I have an odd problem: I've got an AJAX file uploader (fineuploader, as it happens), with a server-side script (PHP) that handles the upload. Although the uploader has an "allowedExtensions" setting, I want the allowed extensions to be specified on the server side, so my upload handler checks the file extension and returns an error response if the file's extension is not allowed.

The problem I'm having is that <strike>whereas in my dev environment the upload handler returns this response straight away (as expected) and the upload stops, on another server the upload goes ahead and</strike> the response is only returned *after* the upload has completed. Which potentially means a very long wait before receiving an error message.

<strike>Looking at the network info in developer tools, it seems the browser is waiting for a response the whole time, and (on the problematic server) only receives it after the upload has completed, which seems to suggest that on the server the upload handler script is actually not being executed until after all the data has been received.</strike>

It seems to me that the most likely culprit is some setting to do with how PHP handles uploads / multi-part form data, but I can't figure out what that might be. Would be grateful for any advice!

**Update:**

It seems the problem is the same on both servers (I just didn't notice the lag on one). So it seems my upload handler script is not executing until the file transfer has completed (this seems likely because the script checks the filename early on and throws an Exception if the extension is wrong, so it should respond quickly once it's started. Also, it always responds almost immediately when the upload has completed - however long that takes - suggesting that's when it's being executed).

Is this just a feature of how PHP handles multi-part form data? Is there any way of allowing the script to respond immediately if the filename is unsuitable?

Comment: It's impossible to know what the issue is or diagnose it without any code. The problem is clearly on the server. You're positive the two PHP scripts, and the client-side code for both sites is the *exact* same?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. They're both from the same Git repo, at the same commit. That's why my feeling is that it's most likely to be a configuration thing - which is why I didn't give code (that and the fact that there's a lot of code there, across a couple of files, and if I knew where the problem was I'd probably be able to fix it!)

Comment: Whoa, these downvotes seem a bit harsh. This is a pretty clearly stated question about how PHP handles uploads as far as I'm concerned. If it could be improved, let me know and I'll try to make it clearer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be as simple as the dev server being really fast to receive the file and respond as fast. If the dev server is on your own machine or a local dev server, 100mbits connexion makes even the pretty large file blazingly fast while on a production server that is often outside of the current network, the upload is long...

---

Sadly no, it's not possible for PHP to respond before the request being complete because thats the very nature of HTTP. You can cut off the connection once the request is sent and not read the response but you can't expect to receive a response until the whole request is sent. Although i used to do this with my friends, that is cut them off and answer before the end of the question, i can ensure you that only humans are capable of that feat! Oh and dont do that, it breaks friendships

o multipart doesn't mean chunked upload, it means the message is separated into different parts using a message boundary to separate the different element. If the process started before the whole request was sent anyway, you'd need to integrate mechanisms to detect if a certain part of your request was completely uploaded which would make the web even harder to program than it is now!

You can look at this for an example of what a multipart request looks like htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/form_enctype.html

Comment: Argh, you're totally right, by the look of it! Which means I'd misdiagnosed the problem. Thanks, that's actually really helpful :)

Comment: Your answer was helpful, but it only addressed my puzzlement at the apparent difference between the two servers, not the real problem I'm struggling with, which is to do with whether it's possible to get PHP to respond before the entire file has been uploaded. Thanks to you I now realise I have that problem on *both* environments, but I'm still looking for a solution to the problem!

Comment: Sadly no, it's not possible for PHP to respond before the request being complete because thats the very nature of HTTP. You can cut off the connection once the request is sent and not read the response but you can't expect to receive a response until the whole request is sent. Although i used to do this with my friends, that is cut them off and answer before the end of the question, i can ensure you that only humans are capable of that feat! Oh and dont do that, it breaks friendships :P

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is this true even with multipart data, which I believe is uploaded in chunks? And in that case, does that mean that client-side file extension validation is the only way of avoiding the problem I'm having?

Comment: No multipart doesn't mean chunked upload, it means the message is separated into different parts using a message boundary to separate the different element. If the process started before the whole request was sent anyway, you'd need to integrate mechanisms to detect if a certain part of your request was completely uploaded which would make the web even harder to program than it is now!

Comment: You can look at this for an example of what a multipart request looks like http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/form_enctype.html

Comment: Ah, ok. So it sounds like client-side validation is the only possibility then? If you could add the detail from your comments to your main answer I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks again for all your help!